# Cannot Apply Array Modifier

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys

> Modifier Cannot Be Applied to a mesh with Shape Keys

I have built a rollercoaster track, and in order to continue the build without lag, I must apply the Modifiers. Is there a fast and easy way I can apply these modifiers and get around the Shape Key issue?

Comment: Instead of turing it off, you can disable the visibility of the modifier temportarily. Then it should not affect the performance during editing. There are three small icons above the modifier (camera, eye and cube with vertices) which affect the visibility of the modifier during rendering, in object mode and in edit mode.

Comment: This has helped a tonne! didnt think of simply hiding the track. Ill just have to make the coaster follow the path, then enable the track again when rendering. Thanks Maddin!

Answer (score 5):

To apply the modifier:

1. Duplicate the object "A" to "B" and [remove Shape Keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/how-do-i-delete-one-single-shape-key) from "B".
2. Apply modifiers on the duplicate "B"
3. Duplicate the original object again from "A" to "C", with a Shape Key transformation (choose one for now. we have to repeat for other Shape Keys)
4. Convert the second duplicate "C" to mesh using Alt-C "Convert to - Mesh from Curve/Meta/SurfText"
5. Select "C" (as selected) and then, "B" (as Active).
6. In Properties - Object Data - Shape Keys, we click in the down arrow and, in the menu, we click in "Join as Shapes". This will create the "Basis" with the original shape and a second shape key, with the same name as the object. Now, we have to change manually the name of the Shape Key.
7. "C" can be deleted. Repeat for each Shape Key.

This is based on [SubSurf applying in Objecs with Shape Keys (to use in BGE)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?290760-SubSurf-applying-in-Objecs-with-Shape-Keys-(to-use-in-BGE)) by Mario_Mey from blenderartists.org.

Comment: Please don't just use a link as an answer, try to summarize the relevant information.

Comment: If the link goes, so does the answer.