# How do I delete one single shape key?

Tags: shape-keys

So I added a shape key, but later I had no use for it so I decided to delete it. So I went to the Blender wiki and read the shape key article, which clearly stated *"The "X" button: It allows you to delete the current key"*. So i did **exactly** that, but when i pressed X nothing at all happened. I also tried using the "delete" key on my keyboard, with the same result. So how can I delete the Shape key?

Answer (score 8):

Shape keys can be added and deleted through the **Properties editor** (the on the right ) under the **Data tab** in **Shape keys** :

[image]

Comment: Note that you have to be in Object Mode for this to work... otherwise the minus sign will be greyed out!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the minus sign is grayed out when not in Object mode? I just spent awhile struggling with this while in Edit mode.