# Script Outdated - Shape keys and applying subdivision surface modifier

Tags: python, shape-keys

I've spent a lot of time with creating *Shape Keys* for my model and now I see I have forgot to *Apply* the *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

How can I Apply modifier and keep all my Shape Keys?
Thank you for help.

Comment: where do you want to use your (well known) dragon ? In UE ? I dont know if there is a way to export a mesh with shape keys in a good format for UE ? Have you checked all that ?

Comment: Have a try with a very simple mesh with some shape keys and a subsurf.

Comment: I truly think I have posted way too many things about my dragon project indeed.. :D  

UE4 seems to support this indeed. Shape keys there are called morph targets. However, I haven' t tried that earlier.. 

With very simple mesh, like cube, it's relatively easy to push or drag the geometry when subsurf is applied, but I have an eyelid which can' t be dragged as easily, even with proportional editing it's quite hard to get the shape I look for because there's too much geometry to handle...

Comment: FYI. I dont have UE, but I did some tests exporting and reimporting a simple object with both shape keys and subsurf. I did it in obj, and dae. Each time the result was bad : the reimported object was not good. I dont know if it is to considerer as "bad news" for you... but to be totally sure, you should import some simple mesh to UE and test it.

Comment: There is a workaround here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/cannot-apply-array-modifier. This is the same principle for subsurf and array. It works, I have tested it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer comes from a previous one here [Cannot Apply Array Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/cannot-apply-array-modifier). I simply add some more details in the explanation and a way to do it for all shape keys at once.

Here is a simple shape, which has a subsurface modifier and shape keys :

[image]

[image]

Make one copy of your initial object for each shape key and set for each the shape key to "1" :

[image]

Select these copies and pull down the *Object* menu and select *Convert > Mesh*, (for 2.79 and earlier press <kbd>Alt + C</kbd> *Convert > Mesh from Curve*).

[image]

The modifiers are applied and the shape keys too (these objects now have no shape keys or subsurf modifiers).

Make another copy of your original object, remove the shape keys from it, and apply the *Subsurf* modifier :

[image]

Now select the "shape keyed" objects, and the last copy we just made (**in this order**), and in the shape key panel use "join as shapes" :

[image]

We now have the final object, with the subsurface modifier applied and the shape keys available :
[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for this wonderful explanation. I don' t know what I would've done without your help (probably created all those 10 shape keys again...). Thanks.. man once again :)

Comment: you are welcome. I hope to see some pic of your dragon live : )

Comment: but anyway.. have a check about how will UE accept shape keys (after an export from Blender)

Comment: Yep. I'll let you know when I finally finish it... which seemingly won' t happen in near future if I keep doing those mistakes that I'm doing (but it's really good to go through all those mistakes by myself so I could understand how much pain they can cause :) ).

Yup. I'm trying to get to know it better. I have quite many problems already with UE4 by understanding what can be done or what can't.. For example, today I spent the whole day trying to understand whether I should use one multi-texture for my dragon using UDIM technology or use 3 separated objects instead.

Comment: Anyways. I'll let you know when the model is ready :D

Comment: That's some really great answer, it helped me a lot! THANKS!!!

Comment: This seems like something that could be scripted instead of done manually. Has anyone seen a script that does this?

Comment: This is very good advice, however sometimes it's very difficult to apply shape keys to high poly models whose subdivision surface modifier has been applied. If you decide to set your shape keys before applying the modifiers on several models, it will take a very long time to follow the process described above.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an updated script which is tested and working for me on 2.91.2. The script from the existing answers still wasn't working for me in 2.9, so I took into account the fixes mentioned the comment by @paddyg (also had to remove `apply_as='DATA'` from modifier_apply since that is deprecated). It still creates a duplicate Basis.001 shape key (which you can just delete) but otherwise I think it works properly.

To use it, just paste this code into the Blender text editor, select your object, then click the Run Script button (little play button in the text editor header).

(I added the call to super_apply_modifiers() at the end so you could just run it from the text editor. This seemed easier to me than running it from the console, but you can remove the last line if you want to do it the other way.)

```
import bpy

def reset_shape_keys ():    
    for name, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        shape_key.value = 0

def get_active_block ():
    block_id = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name
    return bpy.data.shape_keys[block_id].key_blocks

def select (selection):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    selection.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = selection

def select_last_shape_key ():
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_count - 1

def remove_shape_keys (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    object.shape_key_clear()
    select(selection)

def apply_modifiers (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)

    for key, modifier in object.modifiers.items():
        if key != 'Armature':
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=key)

    select(selection)        

def super_apply_modifiers ():
    original = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={
        "linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
        TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
            "value":(0, 0, 0), 
            "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
            "orient_matrix":[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
            "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL',
            "mirror":False, 
            "use_proportional_edit":False, 
            "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
            "proportional_size":1, 
            "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
            "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
            "snap_align":False, 
            "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
            "gpencil_strokes":False, 
            "texture_space":False, 
            "remove_on_cancel":False, 
            "release_confirm":False, 
            "use_accurate":False
        })
    backup = bpy.context.object
    backup.name = original.name + '_backup'
    remove_shape_keys(original)
    apply_modifiers(original)

    for key, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        select(backup)
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(
            OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
            TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
                "value":(0, 0, 0), 
                "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
                "orient_matrix":[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
                "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL',
                "mirror":False, 
                "use_proportional_edit":False, 
                "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
                "proportional_size":1, 
                "snap":False, 
                "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
                "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
                "snap_align":False, 
                "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
                "gpencil_strokes":False, 
                "texture_space":False, 
                "remove_on_cancel":False, 
                "release_confirm":False, 
                "use_accurate":False
            })

        meshed_shape_key = bpy.context.object
        select(meshed_shape_key)
        reset_shape_keys()
        get_active_block()[key].value = 1
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

        select(original)
        meshed_shape_key.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.join_shapes()
        select_last_shape_key()
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.name = key

        select(meshed_shape_key)
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

super_apply_modifiers()
```

Thank you everyone for the other answers, I had done a bunch of modeling using multiple shape keys with a subsurf modifier on the whole time, without realizing this isn't the "proper" workflow, and then got slapped with the "modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys" error.

**EDIT**: When I first posted this, I'd only tested in 2.90.1. It broke again in 2.91.2, but after updating `remove_shape_keys()` to use  `object.shape_key_clear()` instead of iterating, as suggested by @paddyg, it works again.

**EDIT by vklidu:** I thought @Ned script is outdated, but the script works even in 3.3.

If there is set just a one Shape Key it works fine ... **if there is more Shape Keys, than "Key 1" has to be selected** (under Data Properties > Shape Keys) to prevent error.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to get the ShapeKeys Helper plugin working for this and it wouldn't work with 2.80+, but this worked great!

Comment: Does this un-intuitive behaviour of "needed selection" can be avoided by some script update? Thank you

Comment: Any update on this for 3.3? -- It fails with the following error: `ERROR (bke.mesh_convert): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\mesh_convert.cc:1574 BKE_mesh_nomain_to_mesh: YEEK! this should be recoded! Shape key loss!: ID 'MECube.003'`.

Comment: Oh -- figured it out -- two issues: 1.) I had to delete the shape key's driver. (The script isn't smart enough to preserve those -- so you will still have to recreate them all -- any chance for a fix?) -- and 2.) contrary to the instructions, don't create a key named "Key 1", just select the first non-"Basis" key.

Answer (score 4):

I scripted @Lemon 's answer!

the code is kinda long, but I think it is (I hope it to be) self-explanatory. Just copy the code into a new file on blender's text editor, call the text file `apply_with_shape_keys.py`, and then, select the object with the modifiers and shape keys, (make a backup, just in case). Now from the console execute it like this:

```
>>> import apply_with_shape_keys
>>> apply_with_shape_keys.super_apply_modifiers()
```

the script will apply all the modifiers conserving the shape keys! and will create a new object called "backup" without the modifiers applied (just in case you wanna add new shape keys in the future).

If the object has an armature, the script will explicitly not apply that modifier. Also you have to make sure that the skeleton is in the original pose, otherwise strange things will happen.

here is the code!

```
import bpy

def reset_shape_keys ():    
    for name, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        shape_key.value = 0

def get_active_block ():
    block_id = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name
    return bpy.data.shape_keys[block_id].key_blocks

def select (selection):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    selection.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = selection

def select_last_shape_key ():
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_count - 1

def remove_shape_keys (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    select_last_shape_key()
    for i in range(0, shape_key_count):
        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False)
    select(selection)

def apply_modifiers (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)

    for key, modifier in object.modifiers.items():
        if key != 'Armature':
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=key)

    select(selection)        

def super_apply_modifiers ():
    original = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
    backup = bpy.context.object
    backup.name = 'backup'
    remove_shape_keys(original)
    apply_modifiers(original)

    for key, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        select(backup)
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})

        meshed_shape_key = bpy.context.object
        select(meshed_shape_key)
        reset_shape_keys()
        get_active_block()[key].value = 1
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

        select(original)
        meshed_shape_key.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.join_shapes()
        select_last_shape_key()
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.name = key

        select(meshed_shape_key)
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
```

Comment: I've made a simple change to your code, to give the backup object a more comprehensive name instead of just "backup" by adding "_backup" to the original file name.>>>backup.name = original.name +'_backup'

Comment: Throws error: keyword "constraint_orientation" unrecognized. :(

Comment: what version of blender are you using? I made it a long time ago lol... are you with blender 2.8+?

Answer (score 3):

I just updated the @Bengalaa 's script with @Lemon 's answer to work in blender 2.90

```py
# File: apply_with_shape_keys.py
# usage:
#   - select an object to apply modifiers on
#   >>> import apply_with_shape_keys
#   >>> apply_with_shape_keys.super_apply_modifiers()

import bpy

def reset_shape_keys ():    
    for name, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        shape_key.value = 0

def get_active_block ():
    block_id = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name
    return bpy.data.shape_keys[block_id].key_blocks

def select (selection):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    selection.select = True
    context.view_layer.objects.active = selection

def select_last_shape_key ():
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_count - 1

def remove_shape_keys (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    select_last_shape_key()
    for i in range(0, shape_key_count):
        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False)
    select(selection)

def apply_modifiers (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)

    for key, modifier in object.modifiers.items():
        if key != 'Armature':
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=key)

    select(selection)        

def super_apply_modifiers ():
    original = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={
        "linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
        TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
            "value":(0, 0, 0), 
            "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
            "orient_matrix":[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
            "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL',
            "mirror":False, 
            "use_proportional_edit":False, 
            "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
            "proportional_size":1, 
            "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
            "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
            "snap_align":False, 
            "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
            "gpencil_strokes":False, 
            "texture_space":False, 
            "remove_on_cancel":False, 
            "release_confirm":False, 
            "use_accurate":False
        })
    backup = bpy.context.object
    backup.name = 'backup'
    remove_shape_keys(original)
    apply_modifiers(original)

    for key, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        select(backup)
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(
            OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
            TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
                "value":(0, 0, 0), 
                "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
                "orient_matrix":[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
                "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL',
                "mirror":False, 
                "use_proportional_edit":False, 
                "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
                "proportional_size":1, 
                "snap":False, 
                "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
                "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
                "snap_align":False, 
                "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
                "gpencil_strokes":False, 
                "texture_space":False, 
                "remove_on_cancel":False, 
                "release_confirm":False, 
                "use_accurate":False
            })

        meshed_shape_key = bpy.context.object
        select(meshed_shape_key)
        reset_shape_keys()
        get_active_block()[key].value = 1
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

        select(original)
        meshed_shape_key.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.join_shapes()
        select_last_shape_key()
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.name = key

        select(meshed_shape_key)
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
```

Comment: Thanks to all above for helpful answers. I still got errors running with Blender 2.90.1-linux64 essentially due to `object.select = True` which had to be `object.select_set(True)` and the bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name caused errors for some reason running in the Text editor. The armature modifier also got deleted but easy enough to put back (and an additional shape_key Basis was added) Finally I used `object.shape_key_clear()` to delete all the shape_keys rather than iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed version.

Tested with Blender 3.3.1

Edit: copy pasted code from my gist

```
# https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56795/script-outdated-shape-keys-and-applying-subdivision-surface-modifier
import bpy

def reset_shape_keys ():    
    for name, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        shape_key.value = 0

def get_active_block ():
    if bpy.context.object.active_shape_key is None or bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data is None:
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 0
    block_id = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name
    return bpy.data.shape_keys[block_id].key_blocks

def select (selection):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    selection.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = selection

def select_last_shape_key ():
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_count - 1

def remove_shape_keys (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    object.shape_key_clear()
    select(selection)

def apply_modifiers (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)

    for key, modifier in object.modifiers.items():
        if key != 'Armature':
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=key)

    select(selection)        

def super_apply_modifiers ():
    original = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={
        "linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
        TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
            "value":(0, 0, 0), 
            "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
            "orient_matrix":[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
            "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL',
            "mirror":False, 
            "use_proportional_edit":False, 
            "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
            "proportional_size":1, 
            "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
            "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
            "snap_align":False, 
            "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
            "gpencil_strokes":False, 
            "texture_space":False, 
            "remove_on_cancel":False, 
            "release_confirm":False, 
            "use_accurate":False
        })
    
    backup = bpy.context.object
    backup.name = original.name + '_backup'
    remove_shape_keys(original)
    apply_modifiers(original)

    try:
        for key, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
            select(backup)
            if(key == "Basis"):
                continue
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(
                OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, 
                TRANSFORM_OT_translate={
                    "value":(0, 0, 0), 
                    "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), 
                    "orient_matrix":[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
                    "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL',
                    "mirror":False, 
                    "use_proportional_edit":False, 
                    "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', 
                    "proportional_size":1, 
                    "snap":False, 
                    "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
                    "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
                    "snap_align":False, 
                    "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
                    "gpencil_strokes":False, 
                    "texture_space":False, 
                    "remove_on_cancel":False, 
                    "release_confirm":False, 
                    "use_accurate":False
                })
            
            print("key: " + key);
            meshed_shape_key = bpy.context.object
            meshed_shape_key.name = backup.name + '_' + key
            select(meshed_shape_key)
            reset_shape_keys()
            get_active_block()[key].value = 1
            bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

            select(original)
            meshed_shape_key.select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.object.join_shapes()
            select_last_shape_key()
            bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.name = key
            select(meshed_shape_key)
            bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
        
        backup.hide_set(True)

    except Exception as err:
        original_name = original.name
        original.name = original.name + "_broken"
        backup.name = original_name
        select(original)

super_apply_modifiers()
```

gist version might have other fixes too:

https://gist.github.com/terokorp/c2e0bdadf4cffcc856098b93b84d38a9/

Comment: Understandable to post a link to github, but typically we ask that the answer contain all of the necessary information and links are supplementary.  Cheers and thanks for the work.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! However, it would be great if you could reword the answer so that all the necessary information can be found in it and it doesn't just consist of a reference to an external link.

Comment: Thank you, that is an improvement, I undelete the post again! In the future, please always make sure to give the most comprehensive answer possible, because content to external links can be lost, which would make your post here useless.