# Shape Keys and Subsurf Modifiers

Tags: shape-keys, subdivision-surface

I have found that blender doesn't allow to apply subsurf modifier after some shape keys have been created. So why does this happen?

For animation i can just leave subsurf unapplied in the right panel and my model will be fine in blender's 3d view and only here. But what if i need to export my model 'smooth' with right conditions of vertex groups. There is some tutorial for solving my problem ([Shape keys and applying subdivision surface modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56795/shape-keys-and-applying-subdivision-surface-modifier/56813)), but anyway, is this fact inevitable for all versions of blender and we always must do it like in the article? Thank for your attention!)

Comment: This happens because shape keys work only when all the mesh data (amount of faces, vertices etc.) is the same once the key is created. If applying Subsurf (or *any* modifier) the mesh data won't be the same (hance it's the modifier). It's probably that you don't have to do it all over again everywhere; it's just that the generative modifiers should be applied to meshes before the animation with shape keys is done.

Comment: Hmm, but it's funny when blender allows itself to manipulate with vertex data smoothed by subsurf, when i just left it unapplied for my animation:)