# Vertex coordinates of shape key with subsurf modifier

Tags: python, shape-keys, subdivision-surface

For mesh objects with shape keys, you can access the vertex coordinates of the shape key using:

```
obj = C.scene.objects["Suzanne"]
for v in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["My Shape Key"].data:
    print(v.co)
```

For mesh objects with a subsurf modifier, you can access the vertex coordinates of the mesh with the modifier applied using:

```
obj = C.scene.objects["Suzanne"]
m = obj.to_mesh(C.scene, True, "RENDER")
for v in m.vertices:
    print(v.co)
```

However, what do you do if a mesh object contains both a subsurf modifier and a shape key? I need to access the vertex coordinates of the shape key after the subsurf modifier is applied from python.

I tried to use the first way, but `key_blocks["..."].data` only holds the vertex coordinates of the mesh without the subsurf modifier. If use `m = obj.to_mesh(...)` instead, the `shape_keys` attribute of `m` is `None`.

I found an article that explains what you do in the blender GUI to create a new object with both modifiers and shape keys applied: [Shape keys and applying subdivision surface modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56795/shape-keys-and-applying-subdivision-surface-modifier). Do I need to reproduce all these steps in python? It seems rather complicated and I find it strange that `to_mesh` is not able to do this.

Note: I am using Blender 2.79.