# Is there a way to copy a certain transformation from one mesh to another?

Tags: transforms

Let's say I have a cylinder and I bent it it with a curve modifier. Now I have another cylinder, a duplicate of the other one. Now what I want is for the second cylinder to copy the bent shape of the first cylinder as a shapekey. So that I can insert it at a given moment and the cylinder bends. Is something like that possible?

Again the first cylinder was bent in the x-axis using a curve modifier. The second cylinder is positioned somewhere else I simply want it to bend like the first cylinder but in its position I don't want it to change and find it somewhere else.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56795/shape-keys-and-applying-subdivision-surface-modifier/56813#56813

Comment: It's not exactly the same it doesn't use a curve modifier, see I'm using a curve to cause the deformation for the first cylinder what I want is to copy the exact bending effect to the other cylinder

Comment: You mean you want a shapekey to behave like a rotation/progressive bending? If yes, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. I tried using empties and simple deform and see if it gives a similar curvature but that doesn't seem to work, as in it doesn't give the curvature I want. the problem is that the overall shape is composed of three cylinders. If the 3 were to be joined that would probably solve the problem but I can't do that because they have different functions. The only desired effect is the bending in the end.

Comment: You could upload the model so that people here can have a better understanding of what you want to do?