# How to quickly apply subdivision modifier to mesh with many shape keys?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface, shape-keys

I am wanting to apply a subdivision surface modifier to a mesh, but I can't because it has shape keys.

I tried to get help from this question: [Shape keys and applying subdivision surface modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/56795/147083)
but the issue is that the solution only works well for objects with only a few shape keys. My mesh has 100+ shape keys and it would be very tedious to do it this way. Is there a quicker solution to this issue?

Comment: In your link there is a script to automate the process for 2.91 ...

Comment: @vklidu I've tries using it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I started a bounty on that Q ... so [check the link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56795/shape-keys-and-applying-subdivision-surface-modifier) in a few days ... if someone was interested to update script into current version.

Comment: It was a hell now ... the script updated for 2.91 (from Ned) works even in 3.3 ... but for some reason you have to select "Key1" to prevent error (the first shape key after "Basis" key) ... than it works for me in any blender version.

Comment: @vklidu I've tried the script but it doesn't seem to work for me. All it does is continuously load until my computer says that too much memory has been used up. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I don't have those skills ... and given bounty was lost since no-one was interested in fixing. I don't know how to help. Sorry.